# Can't run Laravel Artisan commands, 500 internal server error, bluehost

Tags: laravel, bluehost, laravel-artisan

I'm using bluehost and I want to work with Laravel on a new project. Laravel is located in a sub-domain folder. That is: home/public_html/SubDomain/Project/
In that folder I got my folders: app, bootstrap, public, vendor. I also have my composer files: composer.json, composer.lock. (I used composer to install Laravel.)
I am using PuTTY to execute my commands. I am in the "Project" dir by using cv.
As I am fairly new to this I am using a tutorial. The tutorial suggests creating a simple table by using:

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

This gives me error:

Status: 500 Internal Server Error

Cache-Control: no-cache

*Then lots of html code with a "Whoops, something went wrong."*

My permissions for all folders are 7,5,0 (public_html, subdomain, project, app.) I set 777 for storage and all the folders inside.

I made my "main" .htaccess on the main domain blank because it might interfear (I don't care about that domain right now.) My .htaccess in my subdomain looks like this:

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain.com/project$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

my databse.php looks like this:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'project_database',
    'username'  => 'project_user',
    'password'  => 'project_password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

These settings worked for cakephp.

I've been searching for hours but don't know where to go next.
I also read that maybe I should put all the laravel files above public_html and just place the public folder in my subdomain/project folder and then use .htaccess. However I'm not sure how to do this, and which .htaccess (main or subdomain one) to change.

I am not very experienced with these kind of things but very excited to learn.
Thank you!

Comment: Change your application to 'debug => true' in app/config/app.php and read the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons(most likely this one): the PHP version in bluehost is probably `PHP < 5.4` so you'll basically have to configure it to use `PHP >= 5.4`.

1._ Basically just go to the CPanel -> Software/Services ->  PHP Config -> PHP 5.4(select)

2._ Create sub-domain(if you don't already have one) E.x.: `mysubdomain`

3._ Now merge/copy your project to `~/public_html/mysubdomain`

4._ Create/Edit `.htaccess` file in `~/public_html/mysubdomain` like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

This will simply redirect the subdomain to the `/public` directory and that's what we want.

That's it.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Enabling FastCGI from PHP Config in cPanel will do the trick.